# Turn query results from one query into columns of another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

I have two tables with a relationship one to many, lets say I have this.

```
**Table Owners**
K  Owner
1  Fred
2  Jason
3  Tonya
```

and

```
Table Cars

K CarBrand
1 Mitsubishi 
1 Honda
1 VW
2 Toyota
3 Ford
```

Instead of getting this:

```
K Owner CarBrand 
1 Fred  Mitsubishi 
1 Fred  Honda
1 Fred  VW
```

What I want to make a query with a result like this:

```
K Owner CarBrand1 CarBrand2 Carbrand3
1 Fred  Mitsubishi Honda     VW
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really but this comes close

```
Select k, owner, group_concat(carbrand)
FROM owners, cars
WHERE
owner.k = cars.k
GROUP BY car brand
```

Sorry for the formatting, I'll fix that.

Comment: You gave me a nice idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to transform the data from the single column, multi-row into several columns and one row per person. This is basically a `PIVOT` but unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you will need to replicate this using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

If you know how many carbrands you are going to have you can hard-code the values, similar to this:

```
select k, owner,
  max(case when nameRn = 'CarBrand1' then carbrand end) CarBrand1,
  max(case when nameRn = 'CarBrand2' then carbrand end) CarBrand2,
  max(case when nameRn = 'CarBrand3' then carbrand end) CarBrand3
from
(
  select k, owner, carbrand,
    concat('CarBrand', @num := if(@owner = `owner`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
    @owner := `owner` as dummy
  from
  (
    select k, owner, carbrand, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from
    (
      select o.k, o.owner, c.carbrand
      from owners o
      inner join cars c
        on o.k = c.k
      order by carbrand
    ) oc, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
    order by k 
  ) r
) src
group by k, owner
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41c1/10)

But, if you have an unknown number of values, then you can use a prepared statement to generate a dynamic version of this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when nameRn = ''',
      nameRn,
      ''' then carbrand end) AS ',
      nameRn
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  select k, owner, carbrand,
    concat('CarBrand', @num := if(@owner = `owner`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
    @owner := `owner` as dummy
  from
  (
    select k, owner, carbrand, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from
    (
      select o.k, o.owner, c.carbrand
      from owners o
      inner join cars c
        on o.k = c.k
      order by carbrand
    ) oc, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
    order by k 
  ) r
) src;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT k, owner, ', @sql, ' 
                  from
                  (
                    select k, owner, carbrand,
                      concat(''CarBrand'', @num := if(@owner = `owner`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
                      @owner := `owner` as dummy
                    from
                    (
                      select k, owner, carbrand, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
                      from
                      (
                        select o.k, o.owner, c.carbrand
                        from owners o
                        inner join cars c
                          on o.k = c.k
                        order by carbrand
                      ) oc, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
                      order by k 
                    ) r
                  ) src
                   GROUP BY k, owner');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f590f/1)

The result will be the same with both:

```
| K | OWNER | CARBRAND1 | CARBRAND2 |  CARBRAND3 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 |  Fred |        VW |     Honda | Mitsubishi |
| 2 | Jason |    Toyota |    (null) |     (null) |
| 3 | Tonya |      Ford |    (null) |     (null) |
```

Comment: With your inner join and @Nils response I was able solve my problem. Thanks!